# How can I create new site (not subsite ) in sharepoint online using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I want to create new site at root level (not subsite in existing site). I am using CSOM for creating site. In current scenario I need to provide the Site URL to client context for authentication and perform operations. Here is a pseudo code.

```
    string url = "https://mysharepoint.com/sites/testsite";

                    SecureString f_SecurePass = new SecureString();
                    foreach (char ch in pass)
                        f_SecurePass.AppendChar(ch);

                    clientcontext = new ClientContext(url);

                    var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userid, f_SecurePass);                  

                    clientcontext.Credentials = credentials;
                    Web web = clientcontext.Web;

                    clientcontext.Load(web, website => website.Lists);
                    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

                WebCreationInformation wci = new WebCreationInformation();
                wci.Url = "/TestAPISite2";
                wci.Title = "TestAPISite2";
                wci.Language = 1033;

                var newsite =  clientcontext.Site.RootWeb.Webs.Add(wci);
                clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: You mean you want to create site collection?

Comment: No. I want to create only a site

Comment: How do you differ between site and sub-site? Anything if its not a sub-site then its Site Collection.

Comment: Create the subsite from root site, so it's the "sibling" of the testsite.

Comment: what exactly is the issue you are facing?

Comment: a site that is not a sub site is a site collection.

Answer (score 1):

The code below for your reference:

```
string targetSiteURL = @"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dennis";

var login = "dennis@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "***";

var securePassword = new SecureString();

foreach (char c in password)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL);
ctx.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

WebCreationInformation wci = new WebCreationInformation();
wci.Url = "TestAPISite2"; // This url is relative to the url provided in the context
wci.Title = "TestAPISite2";  
wci.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = true;
wci.WebTemplate = "STS#0";
wci.Language = 1033;

var newsite = ctx.Web.Webs.Add(wci);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Console.ReadKey();
```

If you want to create a site collection, the article below for your reference:
http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/03/create-site-collections-with-csom-in.html